# MPAndroidChart - draw with data from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, mpandroidchart

Hello I want to display the pie chart with the data taken from the database, but I can see only one result and not all. I do not understand where is the error. Thanks for your help.

```
String sql = ......;

     Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    int count = c.getCount();

    double[] values = new double[count];
    String[] categoryNames = new String[count];
    int[] colori = new int [count];

    for(int m=0; m<count; m++) {
        c.moveToNext();     
        categoryNames[m] = c.getString(0);
        values[m] = c.getDouble(1);
        colori[m] = c.getInt(2);   


    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < categoryNames.length; i++) {
        yVals1.add(new Entry(m, m, (double) (values[i])));
    }
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();//array legend

    for (int i = 0; i < categoryNames.length; i++)
       xVals.add(categoryNames[m % categoryNames.length]);

    PieDataSet set1 = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Election Results");
    set1.setSliceSpace(3f);
    set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.createColors(colori));

    PieData data = new PieData(xVals,set1);
    mChart.setData(data);
    // undo all highlights
    mChart.highlightValues(null);       
    mChart.invalidate();
}
       c.close();
       db.close();
```

}

EDIT-------------------------
I have almost solved, but regardless of the data I always get the chart with equal parts. For example I have these percentages:
`Category1 (15,4), Category2(30,8), Category3(53,8)`
This is the chart, help me to find the error? thanks
[image]

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I think the issue might be a simple misstake in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be that your for loop does not close:

```
for(int m=0; m<count; m++) {
        c.moveToNext();     
        categoryNames[m] = c.getString(0);
        values[m] = c.getDouble(1);
        colori[m] = c.getInt(2);
```

You are missing the closing bracket `}`.

EDIT:

And you are not creating the Entry object correctly:

```
yVals1.add(new Entry(m, m, (double) (values[i])));
```

It should be like this:

```
yVals1.add(new Entry((float) values[i], i));
```